# How do I know what the arguments and keyword arguments are in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to learn all the various ways I can use the aggregate functions in Pandas but when looking at the docs I can't really tell much. Seems like I can pass it more parameters but how do I know which ones mean what?

[Aggregate Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate)

Comment: This is what you're after: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm after. It shows some good examples, but not every use case which is what I'm really after!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct the docs you linked to don't say much (contributions to the docs are always welcome!). But if you look in an interactive session for the docs of an actual groupby object, this will already say more (equivalent to `pd.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy`):

```
In [1]: pd.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate?
Signature: pd.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
File:      c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py
Type:      instancemethod
Docstring:
Aggregate using input function or dict of {column -> function}

Parameters
----------
arg : function or dict
    Function to use for aggregating groups. If a function, must either
    work when passed a DataFrame or when passed to DataFrame.apply. If
    passed a dict, the keys must be DataFrame column names.

Notes
-----
Numpy functions mean/median/prod/sum/std/var are special cased so the
default behavior is applying the function along axis=0
(e.g., np.mean(arr_2d, axis=0)) as opposed to
mimicking the default Numpy behavior (e.g., np.mean(arr_2d)).

Returns
-------
aggregated : DataFrame
```

The tutorial docs contain more information, and this can be found at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation

The possible arguments you can pass are:

- a function (eg `np.mean`): this will be applied to every column
- a list of functions (eg `[np.mean, np.median]`): each function will be applied to every column
- a dict of col -> func (eg `{'a':np.mean, 'b':np.median}`: in this way you can specify different functions for different columns
- in all cases above, the function can also be replaced by a string for the most common ones (eg `'mean'`, `'median'`, `'std'` `'first'`, ...)